# No Activity Found to Handle Intent? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android

I am taking a class that requires a build of an app in Android Studio. The professor is no help and I can't get the app to work. I have never used Android Studio before and I did this entire project purely on Google searches. I am using an emulator to display my app if that helps.

Can someone help me?

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ashly.recipeapp">

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:allowBackup="true">

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action     android:name="com.example.ashly.recipeapp.MainActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:scheme="http//"
                android:host="recipe-app.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/recipes"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Here is my main activity:

```
package com.example.ashly.recipeapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent openMainActivity = new Intent ("com.example.ashly.recipeapp.MainActivity");
    startActivity(openMainActivity);

}
}
```

Here is my splash screen:

```
package com.example.ashly.recipeapp;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.splashTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}
}
```

And the error I'm getting:

```
01-12 12:17:34.255 1824-1824/com.example.ashly.recipeapp E/AndroidRuntime:     

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ashly.recipeapp, PID: 1824
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ashly.recipeapp/com.example.ashly.recipeapp.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.ashly.recipeapp.MainActivity }
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.ashly.recipeapp.MainActivity }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
at com.example.ashly.recipeapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you starting Mainactivity in the onCreate method of Mainactivity?
Just remove the following two lines from your Mainactivity onCreate method:

```
Intent openMainActivity = new Intent ("com.example.ashly.recipeapp.MainActivity");
startActivity(openMainActivity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code from MainActivity and it's work

```
 Intent openMainActivity = new Intent ("com.example.ashly.recipeapp.MainActivity");
    startActivity(openMainActivity);
```